# PlayFramework cannot .save() - into the database

Tags: java, playframework, ebean

Hei guys,

I am trying a simple example to save some bars into my data base,... but i cannot understand why the save method doesn't work for me. I am new into the play framework 'family', so probably it is a minor thing that i am missing.

So...

Here is my model:

```
package models;
import play.db.ebean.Model;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;



@Entity
public class Bar {

    @Id
    public String Id;

    public String name; 
}
```

And here is my controller:

```
package controllers;

import models.Bar;
import play.*;
import play.data.Form;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Hello world"));
    }

    public static Result addBar(){

        Bar bar = Form.form(Bar.class).bindFromRequest().get();
        bar.save();


        return redirect(routes.Application.index());
    }
}
```

And my routes file:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()
POST    /bars                       controllers.Application.addBar()
```

And here is my error:

```
I get a : Compilation error
That says: error: cannot find symbol

[at line20]: bar.save();
```

I have activated ebean and the database from the conf file:

```
 db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
 db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
# db.default.user=sa
# db.default.password=""
...
 ebean.default="models.*"
```

I've cleaned the project a couple of times and still doesn't work ...
Can you please tell me what i am missing ?

Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't extend your model class

```
public class Bar extends Model
```